# Are attributes in C# using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

I would like to know how attributes in C# works. I know how to declare an attribute or how to create an attribute. I would like to know how I can generate specific behavior on specific attribute. Should I use reflection ?

Comment: Yes...................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you use an AOP framework such as PostSharp, there are very few attributes that can *directly* influence your code, and they are just a few inbuilt attributes. You can't add behavior to custom attributes. As such: yes, you would have to use reflection to test for the existence of your custom attributes, and/or *materialize* the attributes (just checking existence is cheaper than materializing them).

If you are doing this lots, you may want to consider caching the information you obtain via attributes so that you don't need to use reflection every time you need meta-data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Suppose you have an object o and you want to check the presence of your attribute. All you have to do is:

```
Type t = o.GetType();
        object[] attributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute));
        if (attributes.Length>0){
            MyCustomAttribute a = attributes[0] as MyCustomAttribute;
            //use your attribute properties to customize your logic
        }
```

Comment: If you want to check the *presence* of the attribute, then `Attribute.IsDefined` is noticeably cheaper

Comment: I agree... use my code if you need to use attribute properties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use reflection to check if the type or member has a custom attribute. 
Here is a sample that gets the MyCustomAttribute instance for a given type. It will return the first MyCustomAttribute declaration or null (if not found):

```
private static MyCustomAttribute LookupMyAttribute(Type type)
{
    object[] customAttributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true);
    if ((customAttributes == null) || (customAttributes.Length <= 0))
        return null;

    return customAttributes[0] as MyCustomAttribute ;
}
```